# Is there a way to copy the Ubuntu desktop menu or parts of it between computers?

Tags: ubuntu

Is there a way to copy the Ubuntu desktop menu or parts of it between computers?

I am copying some program files in my home folder from one computer to another. I don't need the whole menu to be copied just the parts for the programs I have transferred.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default location for menu files (to modify global menus) are in `/usr/share/applications` (`.desktop` files) and `/usr/share/desktop-directories` (`.directory` files) for the main menus. I believe you can simply copy those you want and transfer them because to create new menu items, you create new files.

To modify only the user's menu, the files are under `~/.local/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/desktop-directories`.

Comment: Aren't there any user files in the user's home directories? I thought that menu files customised by a user will be in the user's home directory.

Comment: Yes there are, under `~/,local/share` (same directopries as `/usr/share`) but if you modify there, the menu will appear only for your user but this may be what you want! :) as the programs are in your home directory... I didn't pay attention to this point...